# Java throws "PersistenceException:SQLGrammarException: Could not extract resultset"

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpql

I am calling a function that tries to check if a particular record exist in my table in MYSQL.

The function:

```
 public String get_value(long nodeid,String ts) {
        try {
            String sql="Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL="+"'f0='"+nodeid+"'&ts='"+ts;

            em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
            if (em == null) {
                throw new Exception("could not found URL object.");
            }
          //  return 1;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();



        }
       return null;
    }
```

When it goes to `getSingleResult()`,it throws a:

```
PersistenceException:SQLGrammarException: Could not extract resultset
```

I checked my SQL query and it seems fine so I am not sure what went wrong.

### Edit

The caller function:

```
String v=fileFacade1.get_value(fileID,date);

  if(v !=null ){ 

// if the URL column contains the result, do something.


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you're missing one parameter:

```
"Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL="+"'f0='"+nodeid+"'&ts='"+ts
                                    ^ here
```

Because after parsint the query is:

```
Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL='f0='nodeid'&ts='ts
```

Another thing is that `&` is not a valid logical operator in sql, you should use `and` instead.

Edit: if you want it to be one string in `where` clause, then probably you meant:

```
"Select URL FROM urllink WHERE URL='f0="+nodeid+"&ts="+ts + "'"
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, the `&` is not a logical operator because in my URL column it's in this format: `f0=27451&ts=2019.03.20.18.00.21` so I need to check if value of the two parameters exist

Comment: Then there is probably too many `'`, maybe you meant `WHERE URL='f0=nodeid&ts=ts'`?

Comment: I just want to pass the parameter `nodeid` and `ts` , that's all, what went wrong? I know it's a bit confusing because of so many `=` sign

Comment: I think it works but in my caller function, it's not working though, it's like `String v=fileFacade1.get_value(fileID,date);` . Can you check my edited post to see what i mean.

Comment: Since I am able to get single result from the function, the caller function `v` still returns null.

Comment: Then it's up to your data, `SQLGrammarException` is fixed.